# Pick the max value of id from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. Each of them have `id` column as `PRIMARY`.

There is no relation between tables.

```
Table1 has ids: 1, 2, 3, 4
Table2 has ids: 1, 3, 7
Table3 has ids: 4, 9, 10, 15, 20
```

I want to make a query which gives me the max id of every table.

```
table1_max_id | table2_max_id | table3_max_id
--------------|---------------|--------------
1             | 7             | 20
```

What I have tried was this:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(table1.id) AS "table1_max_id",
    MAX(table2.id) AS "table2_max_id",
    MAX(table3.id) AS "table3_max_id",
FROM table1, table2, table3;
```

But I get `NULL, NULL, NULL`.

It is possible to done that? If yes, how?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: @jarlh Not sure that a JOIN is at all required in what the OP is trying to do here, not even the one the OP used :)

Comment: @jarlh Ironically, this is the exception

Comment: @Strawberry, `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: @jarlh, `JOIN` is not useful just when there is a relation between tables?

Comment: Your query should work on the data you have provided, so I am confused on what your real problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL syntax supports placing subqueries into the `SELECT` clause, so you could use:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1) AS table1_max_id,
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table2) AS table2_max_id,
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table3) AS table3_max_id;
```